# why is my input method for the hangman game failing to function properly?

Tags: ruby

I have this method where it gets an input from the user and it checks it against a while condition. if the user inputted anything that isnt a string or if the user inputted a character that was longer than 1 the method would prompt the user again for a valid input, basically adhering to the hangman rules. Heres the code

```
class Hangman 
  def initialize
    dictionary = File.open('5desk.txt',"r")
    line = dictionary.readlines
    @word = line[rand(1..line.length)]
    @length = @word.length
    random = @word.length - rand(@word.length/2) 
    random.times do 
      @word[rand(@word.length)] = "_"
    end

  end
```

This method fails to function properly.

```
  def get_input
    puts @word 
    puts "Letter Please?"
    @letter = gets.chomp
    while !@letter.kind_of? String || @letter.length != 1
    puts "Invalid input,try again!"
      @letter = gets.chomp 

    end
  end


end

Game = Hangman.new

Game.get_input
```

Comment: _fails to function properly_ is not clear? What is the expected behavior? What happens instead? An unexpected result? An error, if so what is the exact error message?

Comment: @spickermann for example, the user inputs a number or a symbol or a string which is longer than 1. All of these are invalid inputs concerning the hangman rules. The only valid inputs are a single character and only that. The unexpected behavior comes when I try entering a number and it doesnt execute the while loop except when i enter a string longer than 1. As you can see in the while loop i have specified if the letter isnt an instance of string than run the while loop.

Comment: hfesoio, when asked for clarification please edit your answer rather than elaborating in comments. Questions should be self-contained and not all readers read all comments. There's no need to mention in the edit that it is an edit, just don't change the question, especially if an answers has already been given.

Comment: Hint: what do you think the `s` in `gets` stands for?

Comment: See "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"
and "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)". Don't add your description of the problem as a comment; Edit your question, and add that description into the text as if it'd been there all along. Don't use "edit" or "update" tags as we can see what changed if necessary. Comments are for us to ask questions for clarification; Your responses need to be in the answer. Doing otherwise forces us to read every comment throughout the page, wasting our time.

Comment: "This method fails to function properly." is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Hangman
```

Stop right there! Why create a class considering that you would only create a single instance of it? There's no need for one. A few methods and one instance variable are sufficient.

**Generate secret words randomly**

I assume the file `'5desk.txt'` contains one secret words per line and you will be selecting one randomly. So begin by *gulping* the entire file into an array held by an instance variable (as opposed to reading the file line-by-line). I assume `'5desk.txt1'` contains the three words shown below.

```
@secret_words = File.readlines('5desk.txt', chomp: true)
  #=> ["cat", "violin", "whoops"]
```

See the doc for the class method [IO::readlines](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines)<sup>1,2</sup>. The option `chomp: true` removes the newline character from the end of each line.

This method closes the file after it has been read. (You used [File::open](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/File.html#method-c-open). When doing so you need to close the file when you are finished with it: `f = File.open(fname)`...`f.close`.)

You need a method to randomly choose a secret_word.

```
def fetch_secret_word
  @secret_words.sample
end
```

```
fetch_secret_word
  #=> "violin"
```

See [Array#sample](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sample). You could have instead used

```
@secret_words[rand(@secret_words.size)]
```

See [Kernel#rand](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand). The first and last words in `@secret_words` are `@secret_words[0]` and `@secret_words[@secret_words.size-1]`. Therefore, where you wrote

```
@word = line[rand(1..line.length)]
```

it should have been

```
@word = line[rand(0..line.length-1)]
```

which is the same as

```
@word = line[rand(line.length)]
```

Now let's create a method for playing the game, passing an argument that equals the maximum number of incorrect guesses the player has before losing.

```
def play_hangman(max_guesses)
```

First get a secret word:

```
secret_word = fetch_secret_word
```

Let us suppose that `secret_word #=> "violin"`

**Initialize objects**

Next, initialize the number of incorrect guesses and an image of the secret word:

```
incorrect_guesses = 0
secret_word_image = "-" * secret_word.size
  #=> "------"
```

So we now have

```
def play_hangman(max_guesses)
  secret_word = fetch_secret_word
  incorrect_guesses = 0
  secret_word_image = "-" * secret_word.size
```

**Loop over guesses**

Now we need to loop over the player's guesses. I suggest you use [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop), in conjuction with the keyword `break` for all your looping needs. (For now, forget about `while` and `until`, and never use `for`.) The first thing we will do in the loop is to obtain the guess of a letter from the player, which I'll do by calling a method:

```
loop do
  guess = get_letter(secret_word_image)
  ...<to be completed>
end
```

```
def get_letter(secret_word_image)
  loop do
    puts secret_word_image
    print "Gimme a letter: "
    letter = gets.chomp.downcase
    break letter if letter.match?(/[a-z]/)
    puts "That's not a letter. Try again."
  end
end
```

```
guess = secret_letter(secret_word_image)
  #=> "b"
```

Here this method returns `"b"` (the guess) and displays:

```
------
Gimme a letter: &
That's not a letter. Try again.
------
Gimme a letter: 3
That's not a letter. Try again.
------
Gimme a letter: b
```

**See if letter guessed is in secret word**

Now we need to see which if any of the hidden letters equal `letter`. Again, let's make this a method<sup>3</sup>.

```
def hidden_letters(guess, secret_word, secret_word_image)
  (0..secret_word.size-1).select do |i|
    guess == secret_word[i] && secret_word_image[i] = '-'
  end
end
```

Suppose `guess #=> "i"`. Then:

```
idx = hidden_letters(guess, secret_word, secret_word_image)
  #=> [1,4]
```

There are two `"i"`'s, at indices `1` and `4`. Had there been no hidden letters `"i"` the method would have returned an empty array.

Before continuing let's look at our `play_hangman` is coming along.

```
def play_hangman(max_guesses)
  secret_word = fetch_secret_word
  incorrect_guesses = 0
  secret_word_image = "-" * secret_word.size
  loop do
    unless secret_word_image.include?('-')
      puts "You've won. The secret word is '#{secret_word}'!"
      break
    end
    guess = get_letter(secret_word_image)
    idx = hidden_letters(guess, secret_word, secret_word_image)
    ...<to be completed>
end
```

**Process a guess**

We now have to carry out one course of action if the array `idx` is empty and another if it is not.

```
case idx.size
when 0
  puts "Sorry, no #{guess}'s"
  incorrect_guesses += 1
  if incorrect_guesses == max_guesses
    puts "Oh, my, you've used up all your guesses, but"
    puts "we'd like you take home a bar of soap"
    break
else
  puts idx.size == 1 ? "There is 1 #{guess}!" :
    "There are #{idx} #{guess}'s!"
  idx.each { |i| secret_word_image[i] = guess }
  if secret_word_image == secret_word
    puts "You've won!! The secret word is '#{secret_word}'!"
    break
  end
end
```

**Complete method**

So now let's look at the full method (which calls `fetch_secret_word`, `get_letter` and `hidden_letters`).

```
def play_hangman(max_guesses)
  secret_word = fetch_secret_word
  incorrect_guesses = 0
  secret_word_image = "-" * secret_word.size
  loop do
    guess = get_letter(secret_word_image)
    idx = hidden_letters(guess, secret_word, secret_word_image)
    case idx.size
    when 0
      puts "Sorry, no #{guess}'s"
      incorrect_guesses += 1
      if incorrect_guesses == max_guesses
        puts "Oh, my, you've used up all your guesses,\n" +
          "but we'd like you take home a bar of soap"
        return
      end
    else
      puts idx.size == 1 ? "There is 1 #{guess}!" :
        "There are #{idx.size} #{guess}'s!"
      idx.each { |i| secret_word_image[i] = guess }
      if secret_word_image == secret_word
        puts "You've won!! The secret word is '#{secret_word}'!"
        return
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Play the game!**

Here is a example play of the game.

```
play_hangman(4)

------
Gimme a letter: #
That's not a letter. Try again.
------
Gimme a letter: e
Sorry, no e's
------
Gimme a letter: o
There is 1 o!
--o---
Gimme a letter: i
There are 2 i's!
-io-i-
Gimme a letter: l
There is 1 l!
-ioli-
Gimme a letter: v
There is 1 v!
violi-
Gimme a letter: r
Sorry, no r's
violi-
Gimme a letter: s
Sorry, no s's
violi-
Gimme a letter: t
Sorry, no t's
Oh, my, you've used up all your guesses,
but we'd like you take home a bar of soap
```

<sup>1 The class `File` has no (class) method `readlines`. So how can we write `File.readlines`? It's because `File` is a subclass of `IO` (`File.superclass #=> IO`) and therefore inherits `IO`'s methods. One commonly sees `IO` class methods invoked with `File` as the receiver.</sup>

<sup>2 Ruby's class methods are referenced `mod::meth` (e.g., `Array::new`), where `mod` is the name of a module (which may be a class) and `meth` is the method. Instance methods are referenced `mod#meth` (e.g., `Array#join`).</sup>

<sup>3 Some Rubyists prefer to write `(0..secret_word.size-1)` with three dots: `(0...secret_word.size)`. I virtually never use three dots because I find it tends to create bugs. The one exception is when creating an infinite range that excludes the endpoint (e.g., `1.0...1.5`).</sup>